# How can I make EclipseLink MOXy (2.3.2) omit the xmlns:ns0="" on my root element?

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I try to marshal a model generated by EclipseLink. The XML I get is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slipbox xmlns:ns0="" version="1.0">
   <guid>7c555370-ab22-11e1-bfe3-005056c00008</guid>
   <name>demo</name>
   <stocks>
      <stock guid="7c555371-ab22-11e1-bfe3-005056c00008">
         <name>local</name>
         <location>F:/GIT/Git/git/slipbox/org.jessas.slipbox.test/tests/demoslipbox/deliverables</location>
      </stock>
   </stocks>
</slipbox>
```

My question is, how can I force MOXy JAXB to omit the `xmlns:ns0=""` declaration, so that the second line in the XML reads

```
<slipbox version="1.0">
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Do you still see this behaviour if you use EclipseLink 2.3.3 or 2.4.0 (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php)?  Could you post enough of your object model so that we can take a look?  You could also enter a bug if you would rather:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink

Comment: Well, after struggling for an hour to get EclipseLink 2.3.3 nightly installed I'm a little bit exhausted now. It seems JPA 2.3.2 can't be installed together with 2.3.3. So I uninstalled the whole EclipseLink Software, restarted and installed the 2.3.3 Version. The about dialog shows me that the software is installed, but when I want to update my manifest file the *persistence.jaxb packages don't appear. Also in the PDE plugins view I cannot see those bundles though when I look in the plugins directory the correct versions are contained. I will further investigate with a clean install ..

Comment: Finally I can confirm that EclipseLink 2.3.3 operates as supposed. The XML is serialized without xmlns:ns="". So thank you for the hint on the nightly repository!

Comment: Anyway, when I use the techniques described on your blog [http://blog.bdoughan.com](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html), then I get a polluted file with **<ns0:slipbox xmlns:ns0="http://slipbox.org/Schema/1.0/">** instead of _<slipbox xmlns="http://slipbox.org/Schema/1.0/">_. I further tried to explicitly define a NSPrefix with an @XmlNs annotation. That works as supposed. Also the definition of "" as NSPrefix works. So I'm pretty done with this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comment section.  The solution for this issue was to update to EclipseLink 2.3.3.